# Using pointers inside a for loop

Tags: c

I am not sure how to pass a pointer into this for loop so I won't get random memory values. Using a pointer in printf works fine outside the for loop but not inside.

After looking, I am not sure whether to pass my variable using the * or & operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mat1[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    int mat2[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    int *mat1pnt=&mat1[0][0];
    printf("%d\n",*(mat1pnt));//works fine without for loop

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for(i==0;i<=2&&j<=2;j++,&mat1pnt)
    {
        printf("%d",&mat1pnt);
    }
    //int *mat1pnt=&mat

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `for` loop `for(i==0;i<=2&&j<=2;j++,&mat1pnt)`, the final expression, `&mat1pnt`, does nothing whatsoever.  Were you expecting it to do something?  It's equivalent to `for(i==0;i<=2&&j<=2;j++)`.  And why are you trying to print the address of `mat1pnt`?  You're aren't even using the right format for it (`%d` is incompatible, so the behavior is undefined).

Comment: And the first term in the `for` loop — `for(i==0; …` — also does nothing useful. Printing the address of a variable using the `%d` conversion leads to undefined behaviour too.

Comment: If you need to pass a value to a for loop, I would encapsulate the for loop in a function that has the arguments to send down to the for loop. Or you can just keep all variables global(not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass values to a `for` loop just as you could do with functions (not everything having braces denotes a function). A `for`-loop is a block of code that - besides defining its own variables - may access variables defined where this block is embedded.

It seems as if you want to iterate a 2D-array using a pointer. For accessing a value, you need to dereference the pointer (i.e. operator `*`). To let the pointer move to the next element, increment it (operator `++`). And you need to iterate `#columns x #rows` items, i.e. `3*3` in your case:

```
for(int i=0; i<3*3; i++)
{
    printf("%d",*mat1pnt);  // dereference, i.e. get the value
    mat1pnt++;              // move pointer to the next value
}
```